# Writing JSON data in python. Format

Tags: python, json

I have this method that writes json data to a file. The title is based on books and data is the book publisher,date,author, etc. The method works fine if I wanted to add one book.

**Code**

```
import json

def createJson(title,firstName,lastName,date,pageCount,publisher):
 print "\n*** Inside createJson method for " + title  + "***\n";

data = {} 
data[title] = []

data[title].append({
'firstName:', firstName,
'lastName:', lastName,
'date:', date,
'pageCount:', pageCount,
'publisher:', publisher

    })

    with open('data.json','a') as outfile:
      json.dump(data,outfile , default = set_default)

def set_default(obj):   
  if isinstance(obj,set):
    return list(obj)


if __name__ == '__main__':  

 createJson("stephen-king-it","stephen","king","1971","233","Viking Press")
```

**JSON File with one book/one method call**

```
{
"stephen-king-it": [
    ["pageCount:233", "publisher:Viking Press", "firstName:stephen", "date:1971", "lastName:king"]
]
 }
```

---

However if I call the method multiple times , thus adding more book data to the json file. The format is all wrong. For instance if I simply call the method twice with a main method of

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':  

createJson("stephen-king-it","stephen","king","1971","233","Viking Press")        
createJson("william-golding-lord of the flies","william","golding","1944","134","Penguin Books")
```

My JSON file looks like

```
{
"stephen-king-it": [
    ["pageCount:233", "publisher:Viking Press", "firstName:stephen", "date:1971", "lastName:king"]
]
}  {
 "william-golding-lord of the flies": [
    ["pageCount:134", "publisher:Penguin Books", "firstName:william","lastName:golding", "date:1944"]
 ]
}
```

Which is obviously wrong. Is there a simple fix to edit my method to produce a correct JSON format? I look at many simple examples online on putting json data in python. But all of them gave me format errors when I checked on [JSONLint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) . I have been racking my brain to fix this problem and editing the file to make it correct. However all my efforts were to no avail.   Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Simply appending new objects to your file doesn't create valid JSON.  You need to add your new data inside the top-level object, then rewrite the entire file.

This should work:

```
def createJson(title,firstName,lastName,date,pageCount,publisher):
    print "\n*** Inside createJson method for " + title  + "***\n";

    # Load any existing json data,
    # or create an empty object if the file is not found,
    # or is empty
    try:
        with open('data.json') as infile:
            data = json.load(infile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = {}
    if not data:
        data = {} 

    data[title] = []

    data[title].append({
        'firstName:', firstName,
        'lastName:', lastName,
        'date:', date,
        'pageCount:', pageCount,
        'publisher:', publisher
    })

    with open('data.json','w') as outfile:
      json.dump(data,outfile , default = set_default)
```

Answer (score 1):

A JSON can either be an array or a dictionary. In your case the JSON has two objects, one with the key `stephen-king-it` and another with `william-golding-lord of the flies`. Either of these on their own would be okay, but the way you combine them is invalid.

Using an array you could do this:

```
[
   { "stephen-king-it": [] },
   { "william-golding-lord of the flies": [] }
]
```

Or a dictionary style format (I would recommend this):

```
{ 
    "stephen-king-it": [],
    "william-golding-lord of the flies": []
}
```

Also the data you are appending looks like it should be formatted as key value pairs in a dictionary (which would be ideal). You need to change it to this:

```
data[title].append({
    'firstName': firstName,
    'lastName': lastName,
    'date': date,
    'pageCount': pageCount,
    'publisher': publisher
})
```